# run multiple simulations on different target hardware in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is it possible to run multiple simulations on multiple target hardwares with simulink?
I have 2 raspberry-pi's and I want them to run the same model at the same time.
You can do this via the command line in Matlab with:
    sim('model1);sim(model2); 
But in this way, model 2 only starts when the first one is  finished...
Any ideas?

Comment: Ypu can create 2 instances of MATLAB and make each one run a different model. You can even do this with MATLAB command window mode.

Comment: Are both models interacting? Is the simulation intended to run in real time or accelerated?

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would use simulink and I would replicate in one model 2 times the same thing.

Of course every Raspberry Block should have its own IP.

Let us know if it is working.